# Select for max date of the Inserted dates on every month

Tags: oracle

I have a sales table  It includes each sale date in the date format in the sales_day column. I need to find the maximum date for each month from these entered dates.  I am using oracle db

Comment: Give example data please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `group by` month and use the `max` aggregation:

```
select extract(month from sale_day) as month, max(sale_day) maxdate
from sales
group by extract(month from sale_day);
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ead3a/5)

Note that this will get dates from all the years, which might not be what you want.
If you want to limit the rows to a certain year:

```
select extract(month from sale_day) as month, max(sale_day) maxdate
from sales
where sale_day between TO_DATE('2021-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') and 
TO_DATE('2021-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD')
group by extract(month from sale_day);
```

Comment: Prefer use of a range lookup rather than manipulating table data in a where clause

Comment: @CaiusJard Edited my answer!
Is that because it'd execute faster if the column is indexed? Never thought of that!

Comment: Better to group by (and to select) `trunc(sale_date, 'mm')` - that keeps the months from different years separated. Then you can format it in the `select` clause as needed.

Comment: *it'd execute faster if the column is indexed?* - it's not possible to guarantee that using a range *will* use an index, but it's usually possible to say that manipulating table data in a where clause means that an index *will not* be used. The database might see you use a range and think "that range is so big it'd be faster to just read the table". You might also see indexes "be used" in that the DB might scan the entire index (if it thinks it'd be faster than scanning the table) but make no mistake - scanning an index and performing a lookup in an index are very different.

Comment: Generally "if you can get the same thing by not manipulating table data in a where clause, do it that way" will be better for query performance

Comment: Than you so much for your help